# How replace values between text file and matrix?

Tags: r

My text file:

```
rf=read.table("C:\\data\\file.txt", sep="",header = TRUE)
    class c     
1     1  0    
2     3  1     
3     5  7    
4     9  12
```

My 2 matrices:

```
class=matrix(c(1,3,5,9),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow = TRUE)
c=matrix(c(17,34,54,9),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow = TRUE)
> class
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    5    9

> c
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]   17   34
[2,]   54    9
```

I need to replace all values in `c` based on `class` from the text file`rf`. desired output:

```
> c
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   0   1
[2,]   7   12
```

Comment: `c[match(rf$class, class)] <- rf$c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
c[] <- rf$c[match(class, rf$class)]
```

BTW, "class" and "c" are function names, so it is better not to use that in naming objects.